# Texture not showing using Project from View

Tags: texturing

[Solved] Using 'Project from View', my second texture is not showing on the model.  The first texture IS displaying.  I used UVunwrap for the first texture.  Not sure what I am missing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: 1st texture you can see on the window/door frames....second texture to be entire building (not showing).

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have not set the texture for the "white" material (Material), but for the "wooden" material (Material.002) only. **Just add the texture to the white material**.

**Or** if you don't need the white material, just **remove it** by selecting it and clicking the (-)-button to the right side. Since you would have then just one material, everything of this object should then be made of that one material.

I hope I could help!

Comment: That did the trick...thanks so much.  New to blender and its these little simple things I miss.

Comment: btw...I used option two above to resolve the issue...thanks again.